# Version controlling programming in django rest framework for mobile app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framwork. I have four version of same application and code is different depending on the version . So, I am implementing if else conditions in my code.
ex:

```
version1 = ('1.0','2.0')
version2 = ('3.0','4.0')
if request.META['HTTP_VERSION'] in version1:
    #run this code
elif request.META['HTTP_VERSION'] in version2:
    #run this code 
else:
    # run this code
```

Is there any better way to implement code for different app version in django rest framework. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DRF's builtin [versioning](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#configuring-the-versioning-scheme) tool.

Just enable versioning by adding this to your settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.AcceptHeaderVersioning'
}
```

Now you can specify version with request using `Accept` header:

```
GET /bookings/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json; version=1.0
```

To check requested version on backend use `request.version`:

```
request.version == '1.0'
```